# Table filtering in jquery - a more elegant solution please

Tags: jquery

I want to filter certain rows out of a table and am using classes to categorize the rows.

The below code enables me to show and hide row data categorized as "QUO" and "CAL" (eventually there will be other categories.

Can someone point me towards a more elegant solution, so I don't have to duplicate code for each category as I have below?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle_ac_cal").click(function()                
    {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        if (checked_status==true)
        {
        $(".ac_cal").show()
        }
        else
        {
        $(".ac_cal").hide()
        }
    });     
    $("#toggle_ac_quo").click(function()                
    {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        if (checked_status==true)
        {
        $(".ac_quo").show()
        }
        else
        {
        $(".ac_quo").hide()
        }
    });         
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_ac_cal" checked="checked" />CAL<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_ac_quo" checked="checked" />QUO<br/>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="ac_cal">
<td>CAL</td>
<td>10 Oct</td>
<td>John Barnes</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ac_cal">
<td>CAL</td>
<td>10 Oct</td>
<td>Neil Burton</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ac_quo">
<td>QUO</td>
<td>11 Oct</td>
<td>Neil Armstrong</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using inline scripts in XHTML, you should use proper [CDATA markers](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/#mandatory-xhtml). Besides, it's not necessary to test `(checked_status==true)`; use `if (checked_status)` or just `if (this.checked)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your code (without changing markup) down to this:

```
$("[id^='toggle_'").click(function() {
  $("." + this.id.replace('toggle_','')).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Though, if you gave your toggle elements a class instead, like `.toggle` you can clean up the original selector, like this:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $("." + this.id.replace('toggle_','')).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

You could also give them a class and use the value as the target class, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" value="ac_cal" />
```

Then your jQuery is just this, short and simple:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: @fudgey - Thanks :) Just curious, why the interest in `[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]()` today over `.toggle(this.checked);`?

Comment: This seems the most elegant solution to me.  Many thanks for your input.  I'm a relative newbie to javascript / jquery, so love to learn there's always a better way.

Comment: I copied that part from Pointy because it was cleaner than what I had. Personally I avoid using toggle for personal reasons, mostly because it likes to act up on me - I think I'm cursed LOL.

Comment: @Neil Burton: "better" is subjective as there are many different ways to do the same thing as you can see from your answers; that being said, if Nick has an answer, chances are it's the best ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could give your clickable elements (buttons? whatever they are) two classes: "toggler" and then something like "target:ac_cal" or "target:ac_quo".  Then, you can assign the same handler to all of them:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  var target = this.className.replace(/target:(\w*)/, "$1");
  $('.' + target)[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

What that does is pluck the class name of the intended target of the "toggler" button out of the toggler's own class string. Then it calls either "show" or "hide" on the affected targets.

*edit* — oh durr, I scrolled down to find your checkboxes :-)  So those would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_ac_cal" checked="checked" class='toggler target:ac_cal'/>CAL<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_ac_quo" checked="checked" class='toggler target:ac_quo'/>QUO<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code doesn't seem to pluck the target correctly.  If i look at the variable "target" it returns "toggler target:ac_cal" rather than just "ac_cal", which I think was the desired effect.

Comment: I have to ask, why am I seeing `[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]()` everywhere today instead of the shorter/simpler built-in methods, e.g. `.toggle(this.checked);`?

Comment: @Neil doh sorry I'll fix that -- @Nick you're probably right but personally I distrust ".toggle"; irrational I know

Comment: more: @Nick I distrust "toggle" because I want to be sure that I've got solid correlation between the "checked" state of the toggler and the current visibility of the controlled element. I know that they *shouldn't* get out of sync, but it makes me happier to lock it together more explicitly.

Comment: @Pointy - `.toggle()` takes a boolean, on of off like I have, that's why I ask, it calls `show` or `hide` internally already. You can see the internals here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L90

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pKLP/)):

HTML (the id should match the classes in the table):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ac_cal" checked="checked" />CAL<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="ac_quo" checked="checked" />QUO<br/>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^=ac]").click(function()                
    {
        $('tr.' + this.id)[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
    })       
});
```